# Poco Net Library on ROS nodelet: ostream segfault error

Tags: c++, ros, poco-libraries

I'm writing a ROS package in c++ with multiple nodelets. One nodelet use the Poco Library to do an HTTPS GET request and get the response as a json.
There are no problem on compile (through catkin_make), but during the execution of the nodelet, a segmentation fault error appears:

```
Thread 7 "nodelet" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
0x00007ffff66aeb7e in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) () 
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I am using poco-1.10.1-all and Ros Melodic on Ubuntu 18.

The error happens when I call the function HTTPSClientSession sendRequest().
I was able to track down the error to line 272 of file /Net/src/HTTPClientSession.cpp (sendRequestImpl is called by sendRequest):

```
std::ostream& HTTPClientSession::sendRequestImpl(const HTTPRequest& request)
{
    ...
    Poco::CountingOutputStream cs;
    request.write(cs); // line 272
    ...
}
```

that calls /Net/src/HTTPRequest.cpp write function; the error seems to be line 227:

```
void HTTPRequest::write(std::ostream& ostr) const
{
    ostr << _method << " " << _uri << " " << getVersion() << "\r\n"; //line 227
    ...
}
```

Following other answers, I already tried to compile with g++, or include stdlibc++, or include iostream in all the files, without any success.

The error started to appear when I included the function into ROS, as a standalone program it worked perfectly.

Thank you

EDIT:
I set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to DEBUG, added -ggdb (also tried -g with the same result) to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and run nodelet manager and the nodelet itself with gdb and got nothing more than the error already reported. The gdb window of the nodelet only say "Bond broken, exiting"

Comment: Could you build with DEBUG flags & run the node with gdb? That will allow having a backtrace helping the debugging.

Comment: Start with gdb: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

I believe you need to start the nodelet_manager with the gdb prefix in this case.

Comment: I didn't built with DEBUG flag, but I ran the nodelet manager with gdb, from which I got the error. I will try to do what you suggest, and also run the specific nodelet with gdb, and then edit the post. Thank you

Comment: If you build it with Debug or RelWithDebInfo, you get a precise traceback linking to lines in the code with more precision regarding the error.

Comment: I edited the post. I got nothing more than the error already reported

Comment: How did you link gdb to the nodelet? Isn't it supposed to be linked to the nodelet_manager?

Comment: I added the launch-prefix both to nodelet manager node tag and to nodelet node tag itself

Comment: Did you run "bt" to get the backtrace from gdb?